# Detect dynamically the first child of new line wrap with CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, flexbox

I m looking for detect the first child new line on specific structure, a container with a defined width and childs can have dynamics width by different text content length. So each line can be got 1 to X elements.

Childs can be float/ inline-block / flexbox... whatever. 
In my case I try with flexbox but i dont find solution, this is an example of what I want, **but without the class .new-line** :

```css
.whatiwant {
  width: 180px;
  border: 4px solid;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}
.whatiwant span:before {
  content: "- ";
}
.whatiwant span.new-line:before {
  content: "";
}
```

```html
<div class="whatiwant">
  <span class="new-line">hello 1</span>
  <span>hello 2</span>
  <span>hello 3</span>
  <span class="new-line">hello 4</span>
  <span>hello 5</span>
  <span>hello 6</span>
</div>
```

I prefere an Css solution but Js can be fine if really simple.

Comment: I dont think that this is possible with flex-css. You could try and temper with direction: column; flex-containers must have an explicit height in order to wrap, as far as i know.

Comment: This will require JavaScript/jQuery.  CSS cannot detect if an element is the first one on a line (not as of CSS3).

Comment: Any suggestion about html structure or sample of js code so ?..